# Entity Framework CASE statement with ORDER BY

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq

Can someone give me a hand in converting following SQL to a linq query?

```
SELECT TOP 1000 CountryID
,CoutryName
,ISO2
FROM dbo.Countries
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ISO2 IN('GB','LU','CA','ES')
THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, CountryID
```

Comment: Missing `END`..

Comment: Thanks @jarlh. Added missing code.

Comment: @RedDevil maybe this can help https://github.com/ganeshkamath89/SQL2LINQConvertor

Comment: What are your tries? Your classes?

Comment: @ErgestBasha, terrible project ;)  Looks like it starts playing and not finished major parts. [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/) is more mature but looks like it is also died. Probably because EF is not SQL replacement and has a lot of limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OrderBy by CASE can be expressed by ternary operator `? :`

```cs
var names = new [] {"GB", "LU", "CA", "ES"};
...
query = query.OrderBy(x => names.Contains(x.ISO2) ? 0 : 1);
```

Comment: Thanks @Svyatoslav Danyliv, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Note, that this answer will never appear, if I do not reread question several times, especially title. SO do not respect questions which contains just SQL without showing your attempts in translation.